# Find the number of upvotes on my reddit post

Tags: equation-solving, functions, estimation

I posted [a video](https://www.reddit.com/r/ABCDesis/comments/fm8uni/bharat_mai_jo_desh_drohi_hai_unki_maa_ka_bhosda/) on reddit that has more downvotes than upvotes. Rather than showing a negative symbol, it displays a zero. It says I have 29% (edit: now 33%) of the votes were upvotes which I guess was rounded. This means we must estimate the upvotes and downvotes.

If $x$ is the number of upvotes and $y$ is the number downvotes, my guess is we need to solve

$$\frac{x}{x+y}=.33$$
$$x\left(\frac{1}{2}\text{sign}(x-y)+\frac{1}{2}\right)-y\left(\frac{1}{2}\text{sign}(x-y)+\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$$

I tried solving in Wolfram Mathematica

```
In[24]:= NSolve[x/(x + y) == .29 && 1/2*Sign[x - y] + 1/2 == 0, {x, y, z}]

During evaluation of In[24]:= NSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

Out[24]= {{x -> 0.361186, y -> 0.884283}}
```

But this doesn't make sense. x is nearly zero and y is about 1. 0/(0+1)=0.

Then I tried Reduce

```
In[25]:= Reduce[
 x/(x + y) == .29 && 1/2*Sign[x - y] + 1/2 == 0, {x, y, z}]

During evaluation of In[25]:= Reduce::ratnz: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.

Out[25]= Re[x] > 0 && Im[x] == 0 && y == 2.44828 x
```

Nothing is working.

How do we solve this? Could we use graphs?

Comment: I guessed the answer. It's probably 2 likes and 5 dislikes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you can't be very sure unless you have an idea of the number of votes cast, or a more exact number than `0.29`.  The easiest way for me to check is:

```
sol = Solve[x/(x + y) == .29, y] // Flatten
(*{y->2.44828 x}*)
```

Then

```
Table[{x, Round[y /. sol], x/(x + Round[y /. sol])}, {x, 1, 10}] // N
1.  2.  0.333333
2.  5.  0.285714
3.  7.  0.3
4.  10. 0.285714
5.  12. 0.294118
6.  15. 0.285714
7.  17. 0.291667
8.  20. 0.285714
9.  22. 0.290323
10. 24. 0.294118
```

It's pretty much still a guess since most of those will round to `0.29`.

Comment: My guess is since it shifted to 33% it's probably was 2 likes and 5 dislikes. Now it's 3 likes and 6 dislikes.

Comment: Or one yes vote was added to go from 4 and 10 to 5 and 10.